# how to avoid writing the metadata on terminal while coverting gif to mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

below command converts well the a.gif into a.mp4.

```
ffmpeg -i a.gif -y -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" a.mp4
```

but during the process it writes a lot of information on the terminal. I want only a.mp4 file without any metadata information. How should I avoid printing those?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQkrW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-v` sets the loglevel. Set it to `8` i.e. `-v 8`, to suppress all logs except fatal errors. But I recommend `24` to include warnings as well.

Alternatively, add `-report` and redirect stderr logging to /dev/null.

`ffmpeg -i a.gif -y -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" a.mp4 -report 2> /dev/null`

If the conversion went fine, delete the report file created in the PWD. If not, you can examine it for details.

Comment: I added this <find -type f -name 'ffmpeg-2*.log' -delete> along with the above lines which further deletes the file created. thanks.